# Python Polars: Read Column as Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

How does one read a csv into a polar DataFrame and parse one of the columns as a datetime?

Alternatively, how does one convert a column to a `pl.datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first try `parse_dates=True` in the `read_csv` call.

For example, let's say we have the following data:

```py
import polars as pl
from io import StringIO
my_csv = StringIO(
"""
ID,start,last_updt,end
1,2008-10-31, 2020-11-28 12:48:53,12/31/2008
2,2007-10-31, 2021-11-29 01:37:20,12/31/2007
3,2006-10-31, 2021-11-30 23:22:05,12/31/2006
"""
)

pl.read_csv(my_csv, parse_dates=True)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ ID  ┆ start      ┆ last_updt           ┆ end        │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---                 ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ date       ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ str        │
╞═════╪════════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2008-10-31 ┆ 2020-11-28 12:48:53 ┆ 12/31/2008 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2007-10-31 ┆ 2021-11-29 01:37:20 ┆ 12/31/2007 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2006-10-31 ┆ 2021-11-30 23:22:05 ┆ 12/31/2006 │
└─────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

The `start` column parsed as a Date, and the `last_updt` column parsed as a Datetime.  But notice that the `end` column did not parse as a date because it is not in ISO 8601 format.  (I've come across plenty of csv files where Date/Datetime fields were non-standard.)

To parse this column, we can use the `strptime` function and supply the appropriate format.

```py
pl.read_csv(my_csv, parse_dates=True).with_column(pl.col('end').str.strptime(pl.Date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ ID  ┆ start      ┆ last_updt           ┆ end        │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---                 ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ date       ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ date       │
╞═════╪════════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2008-10-31 ┆ 2020-11-28 12:48:53 ┆ 2008-12-31 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2007-10-31 ┆ 2021-11-29 01:37:20 ┆ 2007-12-31 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2006-10-31 ┆ 2021-11-30 23:22:05 ┆ 2006-12-31 │
└─────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

`strptime` can also be used with Datetime columns.

Comment: add `from io import StringIO` may be useful.

Comment: @lemmingxuan.  Thanks, I accidentally left out all the import statements, including “import polars as pl”.

Comment: the option is now "try_parse_dates"

Answer (score 1):

Polars supports two csv readers, one built-in and one based on `pyarrow`.  The pyarrow reader supports parsing dates directly; see also https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/1330. You can set `use_pyarrow=True` in `read_csv`, but as per the documentation, it will only be used given also the other parameter inputs into `read_csv`.

Alternatively, read as Utf8 (string), and parse to string with `strptime`: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.series.StringNameSpace.strptime.html?highlight=strptime#polars.internals.series.StringNameSpace.strptime. This is the method I find easier typically, but may, depending on the size of your data, be relatively expensive as you first need to store as Utf8 and then parse.